# php export todays date xml or json

Tags: php, xml, json, cordova

im creating a phonegap application with images that will be updated weekly, i am able to load and save the data onto the phone. However in testing i have found that many people have incorrect dates on their phone so its been difficult to tell the app when to download the new data.

is there a nifty piece of php i can include on my server that will save the current date as JSON or XML that the app can check to find the correct date(in Vancouver, Canada)? Or maybe there is already a resource that does this. As it is a phonegap app the same originator rule is not a problem.

my preferred format would be mm/dd/yyyy but if theres a good solution in another format i can be flexible

thanks, tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use php's [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function and [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode)
try

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('now'=> date('m/d/Y')));?>
```

Comment: Traveling_Monk nailed it. Stick with JSON for mobile, particularly if using a web-based solution like PhoneGap combined with a PHP backend. Less unnecessary bloat and PHP, as you can see by the simplicity of the solution, handles JSON very well.

Comment: personally i would actually use [microtime](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) @tim-c then the value you return is compatible with javascript's Date.getTime() object.method, and would make for easier date comparisons

Answer (score 2):

XML Example:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
echo "<date>";
echo date("m/d/Y");
echo "</date>";
?>
```